# Characteristic Property for Subspaces Pointwise

Tags: general-topology

Does the characteristic property for subspace also hold pointwise in the sense:
$f\text{ continuous at }p_0\iff \iota\circ f\text{ continuous at }p_0$

By pointwise continuity I mean:
$N\in\mathcal{N}_{f(p)} \Rightarrow f^{-1}(N)\in\mathcal{M}_p$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it does. On the one hand, the map $\iota \colon X \to Y$ inducing the topology is continuous at $f(p_0)$, so you have $$f \text{ continuous at } p_0 \implies \iota\circ f \text{ continuous at } p_0.$$

On the other hand, the neighbourhoods of $f(p_0)$ in $X$ are precisely the sets containing a set of the form $\iota^{-1}(N)$ where $N$ is a neighbourhood of $\iota(f(p_0))$ in $Y$, so if $\iota\circ f$ is continuous at $p_0$, and $N' \supset \iota^{-1}(N)$ is a neighbourhood of $f(p_0)$, then

$$f^{-1}(N') \supset f^{-1}(\iota^{-1}(N)) = (\iota\circ f)^{-1}(N)$$

is a neighbourhood of $p_0$, so $f$ is continuous at $p_0$.

Comment: But how do you know that the neighborhoods in the sense of Hausdorff's axioms for neighborhoods necessarily will be of this form? I mean certainly that would be my first choice too however if the "inclusion" is not injective but merely a mapping then this construction does not yield a neighborhood system as it is not upward closed

Comment: Aren't you speaking of a subspace? Then $\iota$ misled me. If you are talking about general initial topologies, we must replace "of the form" with "containing a set of the form", but the argument goes through.

Comment: Yes, I see thx ;)